# asyncAfter not delaying the first execution by specified time

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uitextview, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to animate a textview to get the string characters to appear one by one, then also disappear one by one starting with the first character after a 0.5 second delay.

I am close, the only issue I have is that the very first character gets removed immediately so it's as if it never appeared. Any ideas, here's my function:

```
extension UITextView {

    func animate(newText: String) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.text = ""

            for (index, character) in newText.enumerated() {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1 * Double(index)) {
                    self.text?.append(character)
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5 * Double(index)) {
                    self.text?.remove(at: newText.startIndex)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, if `newText` is especially long, you'll find that the first characters will start out evenly, but latter characters will start coming out in spurts. This is "timer coalescing", where distantly scheduled blocks are queued up at the same time to reduce battery drain. You may want to use a different pattern (e.g. a single repeating timer).

Comment: Do you really mean to add characters every 0.1 seconds and remove them every 0.5 seconds? E.g. after 10 seconds, 100 characters could be added but only 20 of them removed (assuming your string was that long). Is that really the UX you're going for? Or did you mean to add a character every 0.1 seconds and have each character removed 0.5 seconds after it was added (which is not what the above will do).

Comment: thanks @Rob, this is a good point that I had not considered, I'll probably need to go with a timer to avoid the timer coalescing. I'm still working on the timing of the animation, I do want some sort of an offset, not a direct 1:1. Thanks for the help, much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the first character has an index of `0`, so the delay is `.now() + 0.5 * 0`, which simplifies to just `.now()`.

Add a constant to the delay:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5 * Double(index) + 0.5) {
                                                                    ^^^^^^
```

This will cause the first character to disappear 1 second later.

Alternatively:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5 * Double(index + 1)) {
```

In addition, using a `Timer` here can be more suitable if your text is long, as Rob has said n the comments.

```
var index = 0
let characterArray = Array(newText)

Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { (timer) in
    textView.text! += "\(characterArray[index])"
    index += 1
    if index == characterArray.endIndex {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```